# Calling a variable

Tags: c#

I am making a C# program that uses the WebRequest methods, and I am wondering if these variables are called correctly:

```
var user = args[0];
var pass = args[1];
string site = args[2];
string prxy = args[3];
WebRequest webReq;
Uri targetUri = new Uri(site);
Credentials = user, pass;
```

Will this use the variables and strings in place of (site) and (user, pass), or will it use the strings literally?  If that is the case, do I need to call my variables similar to batch?  I.e.
%site% or %user%, %pass%?  Or will this work alright?

Comment: What if you give it a chance to run? Stackoverflow is a human community, not an online C# compiler

Comment: OK, I might just try using {0} and {1} etc. in place of the variables.

Comment: You are not instantiating the WebRequest object.  This line... Credentials = user... is not valid.

Comment: Is this a console application, Zac? A web app? Can you provide more context? Any reason why you *want* to try the braces alternative you mention?

Answer (score 1):

Well `Credentials = user, pass;` is not valid syntax but all of the others are.  It will not use the strings literally - literal strings in C# are formed by surrounding them with quotation marks:

```
string prxy = "MyProxyServer";
```

Answer (score 0):

It will use the values passed in as parameters in args[]

For example:

```
args[0] = "john";
args[1] = "$ecret";
user=args[0];
pass=args[1];

req.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials(user, pass); // john, $secret
```

Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

```
NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential(args[0],args[1]);

CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();

myCache.Add(new Uri(args[2]), "Basic", myCred);

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(args[2]);
request.Credentials = myCache;
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```